# How to change the node when blur event occur?

Tags: javascript, events, blur

Source HTML structure.

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>class</td>
        <td><input type="text" id="data1"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>name</td>
        <td><input type="text" id="data2"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Event: The `Source HTML struture` turns into the `Target HTML struture` after typing `test1` in `input` whose id is `data1` and mouse focus go out of the input.

Target HTML structure.

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>class</td>
        <td>test1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>name</td>
        <td><input type="text" id="data2"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Here is my JS.

```
function  changeNode(event){
    ob =document.activeElement;
    _str = ob.value;
    ob.parentNode.removeChild(ob);
    ob.parentNode.innerText = _str;    
} 
document.addEventListener("blur",changeNode,true);
```

Why my JS can't achieve my expected target?
How to fix it?

Comment: Try this: document.getElementByTagName('input').addEventListener("blur",changeNode,true);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function changeNode(event) {
  var ob = event.target;
  var cell = ob.parentNode;
  var _str = ob.value;
  cell.removeChild(ob);
  cell.innerText = _str;
}

document.addEventListener("blur",changeNode,true);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function  changeNode(event){
    var ob=event.target;
    ob.parentNode.append(ob.value);
    ob.parentNode.removeChild(ob); 
} 
document.getElementById("data1").addEventListener("blur",changeNode,true);
```

```html
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>class</td>
        <td><input type="text" id="data1"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>name</td>
        <td><input type="text" id="data2"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Please don't change my primitive html structure.

Comment: Please check now.

Answer (score 0):

You are selecting the active element while the event is that an object's focus is lost.
You should select `event.target` as ob and your code should work:

Also: you don't need to delete the object, your overriding all inner text so the object is automatically deleted.

```js
    function  changeNode(event){
        ob = event.target;
        _str = ob.value;
        ob.parentNode.innerText = _str;    
    } 
    document.addEventListener("blur",changeNode,true);
```

```html
<table> 
  <tr> 
    <td>class</td> 
    <td><input type="text" id="data1"></td> 
  </tr> 
  <tr>
   <td>name</td>
   <td><input type="text" id="data2"></td> 
  </tr> 
 </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Several problems in your code:

1. You need to add the event listener to the `input` itself, not the `document` object. You can then simply use `event.target` instead of `activeElement` (input is no longer active after the `blur` event…)
2. You're trying to access `ob.parentNode` after removing `ob`. Try storing it in a variable first:

```js
function changeNode(event) {
  var ob = event.target;
  var cell = ob.parentNode;
  var _str = ob.value;
  cell.removeChild(ob);
  cell.innerText = _str;
}

document.querySelectorAll("input").forEach(function(input) {
  input.addEventListener("blur", changeNode);
});
```

```html
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>class</td>
        <td><input type="text" id="data1"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>name</td>
        <td><input type="text" id="data2"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Note: `querySelectorAll(…).forEach`
 might not be reliable in some old browsers, if you need to support them, see [css-tricks.com: Loop Over querySelectorAll Matches](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/javascript/loop-queryselectorall-matches/)

Comment: document.querySelector("input") ,you select the first `input` ,how about i type the  `test` in `input` whose id is `data2`?

Comment: @scrapy it's pretty easy to add the event listener for all inputs, i've edited the answer